# How to remove the paragraph break after lipsum block?

Tags: paragraphs, lipsum

Usually I use the `lipsum` package to produce random text. But sometimes I want to test something just after the text (e.g. some `\hrulefill` command).

I noticed that `\lipsum[1]` ends with a `\par` or `\newline` or something similar.

How to avoid this so that `\lipsum[1]\hfill{foo}` works like `foo\hfill{foo}`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) provides a starred version of the traditional `\lipsum` macro which suppresses the paragraph breaks, or the package option `nopar` that removes the paragraph breaks altogether:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
\newpage
\lipsum*[1-2]
\end{document}
```

From the [`lipsum` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/lipsum/lipsum.pdf) (p 2):

> ...the paragraphs generated by `\lipsum` will be separated by the macro `\par`, or, more precisely, every paragraph will be terminated by `\par`. Sometimes, this may cause some unintended eﬀects. Therefore the package provides the option `nopar` that causes `\lipsum` to omit the terminating `\par`. For this purpose, the package should be included via
>
> ```
> \usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
> ```
>
> Furthermore, a starred version of `\lipsum`, `\lipsum*`, exists that, with respect to the terminating `\par`, does the opposite of `\lipsum`: If no option is provided, it omits the insertion of `\par` after each paragraph, if the option `nopar` is provided, it typesets the paragraphs separated by `\par`.
>
> Note that `\lipsum*` calls the macro `\ChangeLipsumPar` inside a group and subsequently calls the internal macro `\@lipsum` that generates the output. `\ChangeLipsumPar` alternates the internal macro `\lips@par` between `\relax` and `\par`. `\lips@par` is called at the end of each paragraph and therefore `\ChangeLipsumPar` provides a switch to alter the output of this package within a single document when it is required to avoid additional groups.